# Jinja2 select all values from list of dirs

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm want to extract a list of all users (readers) from a YAML file with Jinja2 (Ansible).

```
- name: queue1
  readers: 
    - user1
    - user5
- name: queue2
  readers: 
    - user1
    - user6
```

I wrote the following peace of code:

```
{% set l_readers = [] %}
{% for q in [{'name': 'queue1', 'readers': ["user1","user5"]}, {'name': 'queue2', 'readers': ["user6","user3"]}] %}
{% l_readers.extend(q['readers']) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Error:

```
Encountered unknown tag 'l_readers'
```

From all the testing I did, I think the `l_reader` from the third line is not the `l_reader` I defined in the first line but I don't understand why.

**Online validator**

I checked the same piece of code with an online validator (http://jinja.quantprogramming.com/) to be sure it is nothing Ansible related. I get the same error.

```
Error: template rendering failed.
Encountered unknown tag 'l_readers'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all users from that data structure you can use the `json_query` filter, like this:

```
data|json_query('[*].readers')|flatten
```

That assumes your data is in a variable named `data`. We can demonstrate this in a playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    data:
      - name: queue1
        readers: 
          - user1
          - user5
      - name: queue2
        readers: 
          - user1
          - user6

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        list_of_readers: "{{ data|json_query('[*].readers')|flatten }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list_of_readers }}"
```

The above playbook would output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "user1",
        "user5",
        "user1",
        "user6"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The `json_query` filter uses [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) syntax. The website has an interactive query tool you can use to experiment with query expressions.